# Как сделать http get запрос, указав ip для домена без использования dns сервера?

Tags: c#, http, ip, dns, httpwebrequest

всем привет, если у нас по каким-то причинам не происходит resolve домен через dns servers, то можно в файл hosts добавить соответствующие строчки:

`1.1.1.1 example.com www.example.com`

Есть ли варианты сделать это в c# для совершения get запроса, чтобы не лазить в hosts?

Например, я хочу сделать get запрос на http://example.com/?p=... , при этом хочу, чтобы ip адрес example.com был тот, который я задам?

Или подставлять headers и вот так менять сам запрос?

````
Host: example.com

HTTP Get URL: http://1.0.0.1/?p=123```
````

Comment: a отку посылается запрос?

Comment: Это [легко решается](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58549362/12888024) с помощью [`HttpClient`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8).